# Samsung R700 Replace Power Jack

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure

I am purchasing http://www.rolta.co.uk/new-samsung-r700-laptop-power-jack-pin-socket-dc-connector-34735-p.asp because of a defective power jack. To replace this is it easy to do? Or will i have to do any soldering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something I do all the time.

If you have to worry about whether or not you will be soldering, then your level of knowledge is such that you would not consider this to be an "easy" task.

When I examine images of this DC jack, there are multiple pins that will require soldering.  This means you will have to take apart the Samsung, remove the mainboard, de-solder the existing jack, and solder the new jack into place.  Since there are multiple pins that need to be put into place, it means that you will have to either DESTROY the existing DC jack to be able to de-solder each pin individually, or you will have to heat each pin and move it out slightly, going from pin to pin until you have removed all.

To make this task slightly easier, I use a soldering iron with a fork tip.  I had to make one by grinding down a chisel tip to expose the copper core, and then allow the copper core to melt away.  This allows me to have a tip that I can place around a pin to heat it more quickly and evenly.  I can then push that corner of the DC adapter away from the motherboard slightly, and move to the next pin to repeat the procedure.

If you were to attempt to RUSH this process, you would most likely remove the tin sleeve that is within the hole on the motherboard, that the pin is actually soldered to.  Removing this tin sleeve will render that solder point essentially useless.

The fact that I know how to do this well, and quickly, is also why I get $45 an hour for my soldering work.  Granted, I could get more, but I have no overhead, and I try to be nice.

You could ALSO get a 1200 watt (1000F) air paint stripping tool like [One of these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004TUCV).  I actually use that same exact model to remove multi-pin surface mounted chips.  Solder melts at around 840 F, so if you take tin foil, and place it over the motherboard, revealing ONLY the pins for the DC adapter, you can use that air gun to heat all the pins at once, causing the DC jack to just drop off the board.  Of course, this technique is not without dangers... if you do not properly shield the rest of the board, you will melt the solder on any other exposed contacts.

Comment: Thanks, do you know of any video tutorials that may also help?

Comment: a search of Youtube for "removing dc jack samsung r700" reveals 9 related videos, one for an R519 but none for the r700.  Although the procedure is similar in general, there are always specific differences.  Watching a few of these might give you a good idea on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Easy depends on your skills. What is "easy" for one person may be impossible for another.

It requires advanced soldering skills since the dc jack you linked to is soldered to the motherboard or other power board inside the laptop. This also requires advanced skills in dis-assembly of the laptop to remove the motherboard.